# Sync between Local Database/Location and Network using Repository

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am implementing a weather app, that gets the forecast from DarkSky through Retrofit and location from GoogleFusedLocationClient. My goal is to save UI data through app closure and configuration change. I achieved it using Room+ViewModel+LiveData and Repository model. But I am getting my location and forecast in my fragment and not in the repository, the goal is to move it to repository.
So that the repository looks into the database and if it's empty fetches data from network.
My current Repository:

```
public class UIRepository {

    private UIDao mUIDao;
    private LiveData<List<UIData>> mAllUIData;

    UIRepository(Application application) {
        PhotoDatabase db = PhotoDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mUIDao = db.uiDao();
        mAllUIData = mUIDao.getAllUIData();
    }

    LiveData<List<UIData>> getAllUIData() {
        return mAllUIData;
    }

    public void insert(UIData uiData) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mUIDao).execute(uiData);
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<UIData, Void, Void> {

        private UIDao mAsyncDao;

        insertAsyncTask(UIDao uiDao) {
            mAsyncDao = uiDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(UIData... uiData) {
            mAsyncDao.insert(uiData[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My separate class for getting the location can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189987/getting-location-using-livedata-and-fusedlocationproviderclient). And for the forecast it's just Retrofit.
How would I go about combining those elements in the repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Basically you want to write logic in the `Repository` which decides if to fetch data from server or local database. 
Fortunately this is very common issue, hence Google made [NetworkBoundResource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/88747993139224a4bb6dbe985adf652d557de621/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) class.

`NetworkBoundResource` is a plain class which does the job of data flow between local database and your web-service using the power of `MediatorLiveData`.

Read more at: https://proandroiddev.com/building-modern-apps-using-the-android-architecture-guidelines-3238fff96f14

and official document: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Very helpful! So I can use it as is? I have a couple of small questions if you don't mind. I want the repository to decide where to fetch data from that's true, but in my UI I want to have a refresh button which will fetch data from network, do I have to reimplement the network logic in the fragment?

Comment: Your welcome. Not at all, I had the same use-case in my app to fetch data from web performing pull to refresh.
There are 2 ways:
1. Directly get `LiveData` from Retrofit -> Repository -> ViewModel -> UI
2. Use `NetworkBoundResource` with little modifications like using `AbsentLiveData` to fake database call. I think this has little overhead when you just want to do network call.

Comment: Perfect! You are my saviour :) one last thing, how do you think I will go about providing my retrofit call with location, I get my location like [that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189987/getting-location-using-livedata-and-fusedlocationproviderclient), do I include my location code into `NetworkBoundResource` ?

Comment: Oh thank you for the kind words. I'll need to know more, I don't have any idea out of my mind

Comment: Anyways you helped immensely, thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: I need to implement one way Sync (from remote MySQL database in server to local room database). Do you know any source or tutorial about that (i don't know what to use between Sync Adapter, Content Provider, WorkManager ... and NetworkBoundResource you mentioned ... Which architecture i can use for one way Sync?